# Get fragment (value hash '#') from a URL in jersey @PathParameter

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

How can I get the fragment (value hash '#') from a URL using Jersey @PathParameter?

```
@Path("Step2")

public class AdResource {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{password:.+}/")
public String doResc(@PathParam("password") String pwd){
    System.out.println(pwd);
}
```

My URL is http://localhost:8080/Sample/webapi/Step2/Password@12#

but the password will be display "Password@12" only the hash(#) is missing..

Comment: So why exactly is the password part of the URL?

Comment: @anthony this is my sample program...password or any other value in part of url

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode/decode the url.
for javascript:
`encodeURI(uri)`

then decode it in java using URLDecoder

Comment: plz give me example..am fresher

Comment: @Mohana Do you know about javascript? Or you just input that url directly from the browser

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have a hash in your actual value, and it's not meant to be a fragment, it needs to be encoded before sending. URL encoding is the proper way to do it (like the other answer suggests).

Note also that there are other issues sending password in the url, such as it will be stored in different access logs, it will be part of browser url history etc. Usually you should not send it that way. Prefer POST body.